# Given a city display the native map at Android / iOS - using an URL

Tags: android, iphone, apache-flex, dictionary, flex-mobile

For Flex mobile there are several ways to display maps using .swc files coming from Google (deprecated), [ArcGIS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/mobile-mapping-app-arcgis.html), [MapQuest](http://devgirl.org/2011/12/06/flex-mobile-development-adding-maps-with-mapquest-flash-api-w-sample-app/) and probably more...

Then probably an embedded browser ([StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) component)could be used with Google maps JS API...

And finally a static map image by Google could be used - I use it currently in my desktop to mobile quick-port, but it looks ugly and can't be panned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="{data.city}">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="BACK"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/low-res/back.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/mid-res/back.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/high-res/back.png')"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[   
            private static const MAP:String = 
                'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&language=ru&maptype=roadmap&size=400x400&markers=';
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button icon="{BACK}" label.landscape="Назад" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <s:BitmapImage source="{MAP + '' + encodeURI(data.city)}" width="100%" height="100%" scaleMode="zoom" />

</s:View>
```

[image]

But **my question** is: is there maybe a way to use the **native maps** delivered with Android devices and iPhones/iPads by creating some **special URL** (`map:///` ?) and calling [navigateToUrl](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html) on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, you are welcome to use [`geo:` URL values](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html). Whether they will work from Flex, and whether iOS supports that scheme as well, I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you - `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('geo:0,0?q=' + encodeURI(city)))` works well with Flex mobile on Android.